# jquery.windows-engine - problem trying open a window from a another window

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to open window from a another window it not found.

jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.windows-engine.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.windows-engine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#menu").newWindow({
   windowTitle:"menu",
   content: "<ahref='#' id='example2' >Example 2</a>           Here",
   width:160,height:230,posx:10,posy:120,
 }); 
 $("#example2").newWindow({
  windowTitle:"Example1", 
  content: "example2",
  posx:200,posy:100,
  resizeable:false, maximizeButton:false,
 });   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <ahref="#" id="menu" >menu</a><br/> 
 <ahref="#" id="example2" >Example 2</a><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE will choke on the extra comments you have after 'maximizeButton:false,' and 'posy:120,', I suggest removing those.

Comment: Also, you need a space in 'ahref', 'a href'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using this library (js.windows-engine), the main issue here was that the object isn't created on divs, but on the original window itself. The user needs to wrap this in a click in this case. Example:

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
        $.newWindow({
           windowTitle:"menu",
           content: $("#example2").html(),
           width:160,
           height:230,
           posx:10,
           posy:120,
         }); 
    });
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle with the completed solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5apk0563/2/)